# Repairing a boot configuration data file

Tags: windows, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo y510p with Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

This morning I woke up to find my computer refusing to boot into Windows. Instead my screen told me:

> Your PC needs to be repaired.
>
> The Boot Configuration Data file is missing some required information.
>
> File: \BCD
>
> Error code: 0xc0000024

No matter how many times I restarted it gave me the same message and I can't seem to find a good solution to it online. Most people still have access to their Windows interface when the BCD is broken, but I can't even recreate it from scratch.

Is my only option to get a Windows Recovery USB key? I do not have my own anymore, but my Windows installation is genuine.

Answer (score 1):

> No matter how many times I restarted it gave me the same message.

I doubt that you can solve the problem without a recovery key.

1. Create a system recovery drive for Windows 8.1 (you'll have to do it on another computer).
2. Boot into Command Prompt(using the system repair disc created earlier), then follow the steps [here](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ht/rebuild-bcd-store-windows.htm) to rebuild the BCD.
3. You should now be able to boot into Windows normally, assuming that an issue with the BCD store was the only problem.

Comment: I will do this, thank you! I have access to another computer, but it's Windows 7. Is there a way to make the Win8.1 drive on it?

Comment: Do you still have your Windows 8.1 installation disk? You can do it from there too.

Comment: I wish I did. I ordered my pc on amazon and the laptop does not have a DVD drive. Everything was preinstalled. I don't have my Windows installation key anywhere either; is that going to be a problem when I try to recover this thing?

Comment: Well you just need to get the recovery drive then it should be fine. Do you have any friends who use Win8.1? In Win8.1 you have to use a USB to create the recovery drive btw. I'm not sure if it can be downloaded.. If you can't then you can also use NeoSmart Technologies’ Easy Recovery Essentials, it should also do the job though I haven't tried it before.

Comment: So the recovery process will recognize that my Windows is pre-installed legally and not ask for an installation key? The only friend I have available uses Windows 7. I'll check out NeoSmart. Thanks a million!

Comment: The recovery process has nothing to do with whether the installation is legal or not :)

Comment: Awesome! Turns out my friend had a laptop with Windows 8 on it. THat should work, right? How do I boot into Command Prompt?

Comment: Oh my god! The recovery USB worked! I just had to switch the USB to load first in the UEFI interface. I'm able to access the Command Prompt now! Going to follow the instructions you suggested earlier to rebuild the BCD. Thank you so very much!!!

Comment: Windows 8 or 8.1? You can boot into cmd in Advanced Startup Options>Troubleshoot (all explained in the link). 
EDIT: Glad that it worked :)

Comment: Just wanted to come back and say thanks! Anyone with this error should just follow your advice. It works! And she had Windows 8, but it worked on my Windows 8.1. Fun fact: I followed the steps to rebuild the BCD, but at the end of the process it still didn't find the file. Regardless it gave me an option to 'Boot to Windows' from the USB key. I did. It worked. Yay!